# jquery update total of textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery function that adds up 7 textboxes and puts the total in a grand total textbox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.class2').keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.class2').each(function() {
      sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#GrandTotal').val((sum).toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

The 7 textboxes are populated by another function. When a quantity is entered, those textboxes are auto populated by the quantity times the price. The problem I am having is that the grand total textbox is not being populated until you tab out of the textbox that has the calculated price. However, if I enter the price directly into the textbox (without using the quantity), the grand total textbox updates immediately. Is there something that I can do that will update the grand total textbox after I enter a quantity? The page is at www.pfacmeeting.org/badgeform2.php. Thanks for any help with this.

-cdr6800

Answer (score 0):

When you auto-populate the textboxes, try triggering the `keyup` event, using `.trigger()` function:

```
$(".class2").trigger("keyup");
```

You should change your script to:

```
$('input[name="BadgeQuantity"]').keyup(function(){
    var a = 50;
    var b = $(this).val();
    $('input[name="BadgeTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));
    $(".class2").trigger("keyup");
});

$('input[name="ThursdayBreakfast"]').keyup(function(){
    var a = 42;
    var b = $(this).val();
    $('input[name="ThursdayBreakfastTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));
    $(".class2").trigger("keyup");
});

$('input[name="ThursdayLunch"]').keyup(function(){
    var a = 53;
    var b = $(this).val();
    $('input[name="ThursdayLunchTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));
    $(".class2").trigger("keyup");
});

$('input[name="FridayBreakfast"]').keyup(function(){
    var a = 42;
    var b = $(this).val();
    $('input[name="FridayBreakfastTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));
    $(".class2").trigger("keyup");
});

$('input[name="FridayLunch"]').keyup(function(){
    var a = 53;
    var b = $(this).val();
    $('input[name="FridayLunchTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));
    $(".class2").trigger("keyup");
});

$('input[name="FridayDinner"]').keyup(function(){
    var a = 115;
    var b = $(this).val();
    $('input[name="FridayDinnerTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));
    $(".class2").trigger("keyup");
});

$('.DrawingTickets').change(function(){
    var selectedValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('#DrawingTicketsTotal').val((selectedValue).toFixed(2));
    $(".class2").trigger("keyup");
});


  $('.class2').keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;

    $('.class2').each(function() {
      sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('#GrandTotal').val((sum).toFixed(2));

  });
```

Comment: Thanks Gothdo. Would I add this line or replace one of the lines in the function with this? Exactly where would I put it? Thanks.

Comment: Gothdo, this still requires to tab out of the quantity textbox to update the grand total textbox.

Comment: What was the resolution to this?